# Winforms Using an ErrorProvider

Tags: c#, winforms, validation, errorprovider

I'm using an ErrorProvider with a code looking like that:

```
private void textBoxLocation_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
  if (!ValidateLocation())
  {
    e.Cancel = true;
  }
}
```

This specific textBox was meant for a user to enter a certain path by either typing it directly to the textBox, or by pressing a "browse" button which opens a FileDialog and then the path is copied to the textBox.

The problem is that when the user types something directly to the text box which is not validated, the `e.Cancel = true;` is called which makes the textBox not to lose focus, but then I can't even press the browse button to select a path. Not only that, I can't even close the program.
How can this be fixed?

Comment: Avoid to do that in Validating event. Move it to your _accept_ data method (to cancel closing) and do it "on the fly" during typing (handling TextChanged or...using Application.Idle).

Comment: Well, don't set e.Cancel = true then. And actually use an ErrorProvider so that the user knows that the data entry is not valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably you're setting the text of the `ErrorProvider` in `ValidateLocation`. In that case, you really just don't want to use `e.Cancel` here because it was meant to do *exactly what it's doing.* Keep the control from losing focus.

That would make sense in a scenario where it was an input error.

So, in short, it just doesn't make sense for you to use `e.Cancel` here.

Comment: But in that case I don't see any case where it makes sense. When does it make sense to do something which is preventing the user from closing the program?

Comment: @YonatanNir, the purpose was to *prevent the user from leaving the control.* Imagine if the user entered an invalid zip code in a zip code text box; you'd want the user to either clear the text box or enter a valid one before continuing.

Comment: I understand that but what if the user doesn't have the information and he wants to go get it and come back to it tomorrow? Will he have to just leave the program open for a day?

Comment: @YonatanNir, or close it and come back tomorrow I guess.

Comment: but that's what I wrote that the user CAN'T close the the program if the text box is not losing focus.

Comment: @YonatanNir, the user would be able to if you changed the validation like I stated. Stop using the `e.Cancel` to do your validation. It's not **input validation** that you're doing. As stated in the answer and many comments, you don't need the `e.Cancel` because you need the user to be able to close the application and come back if they don't have the information.